# SSL error on xbox.client.authenticate

Tags: python

I am following this documentation http://xbox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html

```
    try:
        xbox.client.authenticate('joe@example.org', 'hunter2')
        gt = xbox.GamerProfile.from_gamertag('JoeAlcorn')
        print gt.gamerscore
    except Exception as exception:
        print exception
```

My code create exception

```
[Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is an issue with HTTPS certificates. I guess you need to make it accept some certificate somehow, but there is not enough context on the error which and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving the same error while I was trying to debug the xbox client.

While I was researching the error, I found out the "certifi" module needs to be installed.

```
pip install certifi
```

Installing this module will fix the SSL error.

On a side note, after I installed this module, I ran into another error while testing with a real gamer tag:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

In order to fix this issue, you will need to physically update one of the module's files.

```
xbox.resource
```

is the file and

```
_def fetch(cls, base_url)
```

is the method to update.

Within this method, you will find this line of code:

```
headers = {'x-xbl-contract-version': 2}
```

You will need to change the int value of 2 to a string:

```
headers = {'x-xbl-contract-version': '2'}
```

I hope this works for you!